# Change label value with a function while using multiprocessing with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

### I edited the provided code so it's almost the same as the original code I'm using

I've been stuck with this for a couple of days. This program checks for a group of different users folders, and depending on the name of the folder, a specific case is executed. It also gets some information from the folder name like the user name, time, etc., which gets stored in the "log" variable.
What I need to do is to update whenever this is executed, using the function "updateCurrentUserP2()", showing the current user executing the program in the "currentUserProcess2" label. I tried using global scope but I kept getting the same "the variable is undefined" error.

I'm also coding all the tkinter related stuff inside the if name == 'main', which I'm not sure if it's a good practice, but couldn't find a cleaner way to do it.

When the match is done, it should execute updateCurrentUser() with the log info, and update the label, but it doesn't get recognized. I also tried passing the label itself too as a parameter in that function, but it didn't work either. I hope I'm explaining myself.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import sched, time
import multiprocessing as mp

from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from tkinter import messagebox


def process1():
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    def checkFolders(sc): 
        target = 'C:\\Temp'
        report = open('log.txt', 'a')

        for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(target):
            dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames] 
            for x in files:
                if x.startswith('info'):
                    rootSplit = (root.split("\\"))
                    user = rootSplit[2]
                    serviceFolder = rootSplit[4]
                    serviceFolderSplit = (serviceFolder.split("_"))
                    time = serviceFolderSplit[1]
                    service = serviceFolderSplit[3]
                    log = user + "_" + service + "_" +  time + "\n"

                    match service:
                       case "1":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)   
                       case "2":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)  
                       case "3":  
                            #do some stuff                    
                            report.write(log)    
        report.close()       
        sc.enter(60, 1, checkFolders, (sc,))
    s.enter(1, 1, checkFolders, (s,))
    s.run()

def process2():

    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    def checkFolders(sc): 
        target = 'C:\\Temp'
        report = open('log.txt', 'a')  
        for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(target):
            dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames]      
            for x in files:
                if x.startswith('info'):
                    rootSplit = (root.split("\\"))
                    user = rootSplit[2]
                    serviceFolder = rootSplit[4]
                    serviceFolderSplit = (serviceFolder.split("_"))
                    time = serviceFolderSplit[1]
                    service = serviceFolderSplit[3]                    
                    log = user + "_" + service + "_" +  time + "\n"
                    
                    match service:
                        case "S04":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)                            
                        case "S05":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)
                        case "S06":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)
                        case "S07":
                            #do some stuff
                            report.write(log)

                    report.write(log)     

                    updateCurrentUserP2(log)
          
        report.close()

        sc.enter(60, 1, checkFolders, (sc,))

    s.enter(1, 1, checkFolders, (s,))
    s.run()


def updateCurrentUserP2(log):
    currentUserProcess2.config(text=log)


def startProcesses():
    global p1
    global p2
    p1 = mp.Process(target = process1)
    p2 = mp.Process(target = process2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    buttonStart["state"] = DISABLED
    buttonStop["state"] = NORMAL

def stopProcesses():
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
    buttonStart["state"] = NORMAL
    buttonStop["state"] = DISABLED

def on_close():
    response=messagebox.askyesno('Confirm','Stop services and end program?')
    if response:
        try:
            stopProcesses()
        except: "There is not active service"
        root.destroy()
       
if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    ###############Interface##################################################
    root.geometry('520x270')
    root.title("Services")
    
    frameP1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Process1", font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), bd=0)
    frameP1.grid(row =1, column=0, padx=12)
    
    currentUserProcess1 = Label(frameP1, text="Current User p1", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"))
    currentUserProcess1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    
    separator = ttk.Separator(root)
    separator.grid(row = 2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=20)
    
    frameP2 = LabelFrame(root, text="Process2", font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), bd=0)
    frameP2.grid(row=3, column=0)
    currentUserProcess2 = Label(frameP2, text="Current User p2", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"))
    currentUserProcess2.pack()
     
    buttonStart = Button(root, text="Start Services", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), command= startProcesses)
    buttonStart.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 1, pady = 5)
    
    buttonStop = Button(root, text="Stop Services", font=("Helvetica", 10, "bold"), command=stopProcesses)
    buttonStop.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 1, pady = 5)
    buttonStop["state"] = DISABLED
    
####################################################################################

    startProcesses()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',on_close)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use multiprocessing. Regardless, you can't write code that manipulates a tkinter widget from a separate process. All tkinter code must exist in a single process.

Comment: You never call `CheckFolders`.

Comment: Processes don't share memory so you can't use global variable to send value from one process to main process (only threads share memory and can use use global variable to send value from one thread to main thread). Processes would need `Queue` or `sockets` (eventually file) to send data from one process to other process. And tkinter would need `root.after(millisecond, function)` to run periodically function which would check if there is new valu in `Queue` (`socket`, `file`)

Answer (score 1):

`Processes` don't share memory so you can't use `global` variable to send value from one process to main process. Only `threads` share memory and can use global variable to send value from one thread to main thread.

Processes would need `Queue` (or `sockets`, `file`, `database`) to send data from one process to other process.

And `tkinter` would need `root.after(millisecond, function)` to run periodically function which would check if there is new value in `Queue` (`socket`, `file`, `database`)

---

Minimal working code.

It use `multiprocessing.Queue` to send current time from process to `tkinter`. And `tkinter` uses `root.after()` to check periodically queue and update `label`.

```
import multiprocessing
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import time

def check_folders(queue):   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables
    # function has to get queue as parameter

    while True:
        # do something
        time.sleep(0.5)

        # send information to tkinter
        data = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')             # string
        #data = {'time': time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}  # dict
        queue.put(data)

def check_queue():
    # get data from queue
    if not queue.empty():  # while not queue.empty():
        data = queue.get()
        label['text'] = data           # string
        #label['text'] = data['time']  # dict

    # run again after 500ms (0.5s)
    root.after(500, check_queue)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create queue
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # send queue to process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=check_folders, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    root = tk.Tk()

    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.pack()

    check_queue()  # start checking queue

    root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Ohh I see! I'll look for sockets and queues, or try to replicate it with threads then. Thank you very much!